# Oracle db workload testing with TPC-H hammerdb

Tags: oracle11g, workload, tpc

What is the workload percentage of DML/Select operations in hammerdb TPC-H???

As calling circle of oracle swingbench benchmark percentage is like Large amounts of dynamic PL/SQL.

Heavy CPU utilization

```
• Select 83% 
• Insert 7% 
• Update 10% 
• Delete 0%
```

Answer (score 0):

The query streams are all SELECT, complex adhoc queries that make good use of parallel query/direct path reads and/or column store. If the refresh function is enabled one connection will then do all INSERT followed by all DELETE. If running at the same time as the query throughput workload this function can be trickled so the refresh occurs slowly. Therefore consider TPC-H as a SELECT workload.